# NewRelicAgent does not work with OCTesting

Tags: ios, ocunit, newrelic, cocoapods

I have a problem with the NewRelicAgent pod.
It works fine with the nomral app targed und runs well in the simulator, but as soon as I start the test target, I get the the following error message:

```
ld: framework not found NewRelicAgent
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My pod file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0rc'

pod 'RestKit/Testing', '~> 0.20.0rc'

pod 'RestKit/Search', '~> 0.20.0rc'

target :test do

    link_with :DealiniTests

    pod 'Expecta', '0.2.1'

end

pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.0beta4'

pod 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 1.328.0'

pod 'Parse', '~> 1.2.9'
```

I think the problem is, that the PATHS links to a path "{PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/NewRelicAgent" which does not exsits.
I have no NewRelicAgent folder in the Headers and BuildHeaders folder but it does work for the normal target just for the test target not.

All other pods works fin just the newrelic does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Problem is, that CocoaPods does not automaticly add the NewRelic framework to the

**FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS**

I just added "$(PODS_ROOT)/NewRelicAgent/NewRelic_iOS_Agent_1.328" to the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS of the test target and it worked

Comment: I added Pods/NewRelicAgent and made it recursive. Pretty much what you said and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would be a good solution, but try to add pod `'NewRelicAgent', '~> 1.328.0'` to your test target as well. I did that in order to be able to use RestKit classes in my tests. The only difference is that I have my test target declared as exclusive in my podfile.

Comment: that do you mean with: you have the test targed declared as exlusive

Comment: It is explained in this doc: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/A-Podfile

Answer (score 0):

try adding $(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS) to your "Framework Search Paths" in the test target build settings. It appears cocoapods doesn't set up the headers and search paths correctly for this particular pod.